# C# MongoDB exception when writing document to Atlas server

Tags: c#, mongodb, exception, nosql, connection

I'm trying to connect to a MongoDB Database using the MongoDB .NET API. It works fine and is able to write documents on localhost without credentials, but when I try to connect to a MongoDB Atlas server with credentials, it gives an exception when trying to write the document.

```
Client = new MongoClient($"mongodb://{txtUsername.Text}:{txtPassword.Password}@{txtServer.Text}:{txtPort.Text}/{txtAuthDatabase.Text}");
var collection = Client.GetDatabase("TestDatabase").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("TestCollection");
var document = new BsonDocument { { "testKey", "testValue" } };
collection.InsertOne(document); //Exception here
```

I also tried adding ?connect=replicaSet to connection string but it doesn't seem to do anything

The exception is

```
    System.TimeoutException
  HResult=0x80131505
  Message=A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/achille-shard-00-00-mdhfu.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/achille-shard-00-00-mdhfu.mongodb.net:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid BinaryConnection state transition from 4 to Failed.
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenConnectionHelper.FailedOpeningConnection(Exception wrappedException)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.<HeartbeatAsync>d__27.MoveNext()" }] }.
  Source=MongoDB.Driver.Core
  StackTrace:
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedHelper.HandleCompletedTask(Task completedTask)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChanged(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description, Task descriptionChangedTask, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServer(IServerSelector selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupportedAfterServerSelection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupported(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.StartImplicitSession(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSession[TResult](Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWrite(IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.<>c__DisplayClass58_0.<InsertOne>b__0(IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions bulkWriteOptions)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.InsertOne(TDocument document, InsertOneOptions options, Action`2 bulkWrite)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.InsertOne(TDocument document, InsertOneOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Gestione_Fatture_Casa_Di_Riposo.MainWindow.btnConnect_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\achil\source\repos\Gestione Fatture Casa Di Riposo\Gestione Fatture Casa Di Riposo\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 46
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at Gestione_Fatture_Casa_Di_Riposo.App.Main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this format for your connection string:

```
mongodb://[username]:[password]@[host]:[port],[host]:[port],,[host]:[port]/test?ssl=[bool]&replicaSet=[replicasetName]&authSource=[authdbname]
```

Obviously change this to reflect how many hosts you have, the example above assumed you have 3 in your replicaset..

You should be able to get your connection string directly from Atlas. I did and this is the format I have for my sandbox which is on a replicaset